# How to solve 1^n=1 for n=0?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

If it is not apparent from the question title, I am okay with math but not brilliant.

For the following:

$$
1^n=1
$$

How is this solved for n=0 ?

Wolfram Alpha says this is [true](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%5E0) and explains any nonzero number to the zero power is one.

EDIT: To ask more clearly, how is it true that any nonzero number to the zero power is one when it *seems* from my limited understanding that one multiplied by itself zero times should be zero - I have zero ones in a row with the multiplication of each one.

I am asking for an elementary explanation.

Comment: hint $a^n/a^n=1$

Comment: it is by definition 1

Comment: The starting state for multiplication is $1$, not $0$. So starting with $1$, multiply by $1$ zero times, and you get ??

Comment: @quasi I would like to see you write that up as an answer.

Comment: @Willtech: Since the question was put on hold, answers are no longer postable. But here's a little more explanation. For addition, the starting value should be zero, so that when you start adding, the starting value doesn't affect the sum. Analogously, for multiplication, the starting value should be $1$, so that when you start multiplying, the starting value doesn't affect the product. As a consequence, the empty sum is $0$, and the empty product is $1$.

Comment: @quasi Simple, so if I write 5 it is actually 0 + 5 or 1 x 5 and if I write no 5's when using multiplication it is 1.

Comment: @Willtech: Exactly. The same concept also explains why $0!=1$.

Comment: @quasi If it comes off hold (if my edit is acceptable?) I would be pleased if you would write it up as an answer, it is worth reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition for $a\neq0$

$$a^n =\stackrel{\color{red}{\text{n terms}}} {a\cdot a \cdot a\cdot...\cdot a}$$

and

$$a^{n-m} =\frac{\stackrel{\color{red}{\text{n terms}}}{a\cdot a \cdot a\cdot...\cdot a}}{\stackrel{\color{red}{\text{m terms}}}{a\cdot a \cdot a\cdot...\cdot a}}$$

thus by definition

$$a^0=a^{n-n}=\frac{\stackrel{\color{red}{\text{n terms}}}{a\cdot a \cdot a\cdot...\cdot a}}{\stackrel{\color{red}{\text{n terms}}}{a\cdot a \cdot a\cdot...\cdot a}}=1$$

Comment: Okay, I can follow that.